# I've refreshed ul tag so jQuery styles can be applied but my page just displays a loading jQuery image

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile, woocommerce

I'm developing a woocommerce theme for wordpress and I'm trying to add some attributes to an `<ul>` element so jQuery mobile styles can be applied to it.

To do this I've enqueued a script to the hook named 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop'.

The scrypt is as follows:

```
(function ($){
$(document).on('pageinit','#shop', function(){
    $('ul').attr('data-role', 'listview');
    $('ul').attr('data-inset','true');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

With this script I've managed to add the attributes to the `<ul>` tag I wanted. But this way jquery mobile styles are not applied.
Then I've refreshed the list so jquery can add its class atributes dinamically. The new script is:

```
(function ($){
$(document).on('pageinit','#shop', function(){
    $('ul').attr('data-role', 'listview');
    $('ul').attr('data-inset','true');
    $('ul').listview(); // to refresh the <ul> tag
});
})(jQuery);
```

Like this what I have accomplished is that jquery can add its classes dinamically and I've been able to check it by using the chrome console. But now that jQuery classes are added my page isn't displaying any content, it just displays the jQuery loading image but the content never shows.

Here you can see my website: http://danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/shop/ and the loading image. You also can check with the chrome console that inside the `<div id="shop" ...>` the attributes I've set in my script and the class from jQuery have been added to the `<ul>` tag.

I hope someone can help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: working fine, no loading spinner.

Comment: Then why am I seeing it?? Do you see it styled with jquerystyle the <ul> tag Omar?

Comment: Ii was a cache problem...but now I'm having another issue! If I go to the page using danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/shop the styles are applied but If I go from the home page danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress they are not. Any ideas Omar?? Thank you for checking my site and telling me it's actually working

Comment: remove these `(function ($){` and `})(jQuery);`. and try `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow` instead of `pageinit`.

Comment: Not working. With these changes my script is doing nothing :(

Comment: Put back function as before. I forgot its a WP.

Comment: Any ideas then @Omar? I'm sorry to bother you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36804/discussion-between-omar-and-ered)